# perl script not executed in one three virtual hosts configured the same

Tags: linux, perl, apache2, cgi

I have three virtual hosts on apache2 web server.
Two of them use perl scripts that are working perfectly.
The third I just created with EXACTLY THE SAME configuration concerning the ScriptAlias directive

Number one: working

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/www/old/uep/cgi-bin/"

Number two: working

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/www/cssm/formulaire/cgi-bin/"

Number three: not working

(the perl script is about to be downloaded instead of being executed as the two others)

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/www/cssm/juin2019/cgi-bin/"

All the hosts are configured the same, all the scripts have sufficient rights to be executed, but only the last can not be executed.

Checked logs: no errors, the access log file indicates GET concerning the script with .pl extension and with execution permission.

Emptied the browser cache (everything).

Kompared the three involved .conf files in /etc/apache2/vhosts.d

All of the three .conf files are the same, with no difference but the path and the error/access log names.

I use the following settings in the three .conf files concerning the main directory

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8 NameWidth=*

I don't use symbolic links in the path.
In the HTML file I use a FORM for one of the two site that are working, and a direct link /cgi-bin/forum.pl for the other working site.

NOT WORKING:

192.168.0.4 - - [02/Apr/2019:19:32:54 +0200] "GET /cgi-bin/examenjuin.pl HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://www.examenjuin2019.cssm/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"

WORKING:

192.168.0.4 - - [02/Apr/2019:19:51:38 +0200] "GET /cgi-bin/forum.pl HTTP/1.1" 200 2209 "http://www.uepsoundsystem.dezordi.world/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"

Can not understand why two perl scripts in different folders with exactly the same permissions are working and this one can't...

Answer (score 0):

If it is not your script producing the `304` status code, it is your server configuration.
On Apache, [play around with `mod_cache` settings](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/304-not-modified) to prevent your server from sending them.

Comment: I do not use mod_cache module AFAIK